# Is there a way to login to amazon.com programatically in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to programmatically get to the order details page if I have the order-id, username, password? I would assume I would have to login to amazon.com programmatically.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: How do I get order details (programmatically) from order id if I am not a seller. I have the username, password associated with the account that ordered it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Order API for Amazon Marketplace](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/orders/MWSOrdersApiReference._V167604017_.pdf).  If you are a seller and want to know what orders have been placed TO you, that's the way to go.

If you are a purchaser and want to check orders placed BY you, the best option I know of is screen scraping (there may be an API I'm not familiar with however).  I have used [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) in the past for this type of thing.  It allows you to log into a website and then assists in parsing a page you are interested in, which could be an order page.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. While trying to login to amazon.com from a browser, somehow the browser is generating "metadata1" field which is not part of the cookie. If I get the value of this one, I might be able to login.

Comment: @AnupamGodbole: Is the "metadata1" field a hidden form field, or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Yes. It's a hidden form field which is not part of the cookie.

Comment: @AnupamGodbole: You could programatically set `metadata1`, but I don't know what value should be set there.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. Donno what value to set. And without that value, login doesn't seem to be happening successfully.